# on Ajax link click javascript error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my partial view I have this ajax actionlink

```
@foreach (var times in Model.ProvidedDateTimes)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @times.StartDateTime &nbsp; to &nbsp; @times.EndDateTime
        </td>
        <td> @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteResponse", new { responseid = @times.ResponseId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="dummy",OnBegin = "begin",OnComplete="complete",OnFailure="fail",OnSuccess = "success"})</td>
    </tr>
}
```

These are the functions

```
$(function begin() {
    alert("begin");
});
$(function complete() {
    alert("complete");
});
$(function fail() {
    alert("fail");
});

function deleteResponse(id){
        var url = $("#providedTimes").data('url');
        url = url + "&t=" + new Date().getTime();

        $.get(url, function (data) {

            $('#providedTimes').html(data);
        });
    };
```

When I run the application I get javascript alert begin complete then fail, all twice.

When i try to click the delete i get error on console that says
[image]
The bundles I render are

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

and in _layout view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Kendo")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/toastr")
```

Any idea why I'm getting error in console?

Comment: Why have you encapsulated your functions within `$()`? Perhaps if your page just said `function begin()` instead of `$(function begin(){})`

Comment: You are creating your functions in your `document.ready` event. they are not available outside of it. Create a `<script>` tag before your form (or `foreach`...) and define the functions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a function like this:

```
$(function begin() {
    alert("begin");
});
```

You're not *really* "defining" the function in the way that you think.  `$()` expects a function as a parameter, and you're giving it one.  All it does is execute that function.  Once it's done, that definition isn't retained.  So immediately following this statement, `begin` is no longer in scope anywhere else.

Just define your functions directly:

```
function begin() {
    alert("begin");
};
```

If you want to execute that function when the document is ready, you can still pass it to the jQuery object:

```
$(begin);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want that instead:

```
function begin() {
    alert("begin");
};

$(begin);
```

And the same for all other methods. Even not sure you want to call Fail/Complete on ready handler.